# Kubernetes C# Client - stop and start pod or restart pod

Tags: kubernetes

i used with kubernetes client and i want to stop and start one pod that i found in my code,
for example:

```
            var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigFile(path);
            var client = new Kubernetes(config);    
            ...    
            var list = client.ListNamespacedPod(nameSpace);   
            var currentPod = list.Items.FirstOrDefault(...); 
            
            // what to do here? i need something like that:
            // currentPod.Stop();
            // currentPod.Start();
            // or currentPod.Restart(); 
            // or scale to 0 and after scale to 1
```

i searching here:
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp
but i don't found the solution.
any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: "Stop" isn't a valid verb for pods; you need to delete the pod (or set its controlling deployment to 0 replicas).  [how to stop/pause a pod in kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54821044/how-to-stop-pause-a-pod-in-kubernetes) has the CLI equivalent.

Comment: @David Mazeok so if i want to set its controlling deployment to 0 how i do it with c# code?