# kubernetes: Dont launch a container configured in yaml

Tags: kubernetes

I have configured 2 containers in k8s yaml, and both are spawned as expected.

What if I want to ensure that one of them doesn't launch(without removing corresponding entry from yaml)?

Can setting requested cpu to 0 work?

Comment: could you please explain why do you need a pod not in a running state?

Comment: Actually I share a testing env with others. Container in question is for my purpose only, hence.

Comment: just to check: "ensure that one of them doesn't launch" with that you mean that you want the Pod to show when you run `kubectl get pod` and not running state? if that's what you want, how will you use that container in a not running state? remember that kubernetes doesn't support stop or paused states, like you'd expect from docker (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54822866/20269772)

Comment: No, I don't even want pod to show.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. maybe you could use a different namespace than your colleagues

Comment: Can you split this into two separate Deployments, each with only one container?  That's usually better practice, and it would let you run a different number of replicas for each container.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a separate pod for each of the two containers that you are launching. If so, the simplest way to constrain a pod from getting scheduled would be to add a nodeSelector label to the pod - a nodeSelector label that does not match labels on any of your nodes.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp
    image: myapp
  nodeSelector:
    machine: neverThere
```

If you do not want to see the unscheduled pod from the pod that is getting scheduled (as you had indicated in one of your messages) then you need to have them in a different namespaces.

Comment: really interesting way to avoid Pod from being scheduled